# subpixels not rendered in display: table

Tags: css

I'm coming across a weird bug in how the browser (I've only tested in chrome) renders subpixels in `display: table;` vs. `display: block;`.

I set up a fiddle to show you what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/K7ZLV/

When the container has a percent width, `display: table` doesn't read subpixels, so the child with `display: block;` has a computed width of 460.796875px, where the child with `display: table;` has a computer width of 460px.

Is there any way to solve this to provide consistency that would be supported back through ie8?